# How should login screen appear on start of application IOS

Tags: ios, storyboard, appdelegate, tabbarcontroller

I am making a new application there i have 5 tabs in it,  its a user based application so i have to get the credentials of users login and passwords .

I am using storyboards with Arc , since its a Tabbed application so my initial view controller is my tab view controller , I wish to add a login screen also (probably as Modal View or an).

I am not able to think the perfect way to add a login screen in the tabbed application .

Should i call it from app delegate or in view will appear or some of these methods . I tried some of the code but ended up with warning like unbalanced call etc.

Need your valuable suggestions :)

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just two options (of course there are more):

1. Use one `UIViewController` as `rootViewController` in the beginning of your App. Once the login is successful it will switch the `window`'s `rootViewController`.
2. Put the `UITabBarController` as `rootViewController`, on `viewWillAppear`, check if the login has been made, if not, just show the Login's `UIViewController`

Comment: well second option sounds good , i think using NSUSERDEFAULTS will work in your 2nd Scenario. looking forward for more options :)

Comment: I would go for the first one, think it's cleaner, but if you prefer the 2n one, go ahead man.

Comment: well i tried 2 nd one the issue i am facing is that i am getting a warning when i placed a code to get a view controller in VIeWdidApper Attempt to present <loginPage: 0x714ccb0> on <UITabBarController: 0x71411d0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!  ONE more thing how to Do 1st one ?

Comment: You need a protocol and a reference to the AppDelegate that you pass to the loginViewController, you then do something like `[myDelegate switchRootViewController];`